# Itextsharp pdf GridView Positioning

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview

I am working with asp.net application and in which i am using itexsharp to generate pdf file. I need to export my gridview to pdf and the problem is after generating pdf the gridview is always postioning at the top of the page. My requriement is i need the gridview at the centre of the page and at the top i will have some text entered throught the textbox from the front end..
Please help me to find solution for this and Thanks in Advance 
here is the code for my button click:

Here is my code for the button click to generate PDF:

```
{

    string name = TextBox1.Text;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Chunk c = new Chunk("Export GridView to PDF Using iTextSharp \n",FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 15));
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    p.Add(c);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    string s = sw.ToString();
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    BindDDL();
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    var wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("D:/xyz" + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/bill.htm"));
    contents = contents.Replace("[CNAME]", name);
    var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(contents), null);
    foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
    pdfDoc.Add(htmlElement as IElement);
    pdfDoc.Add(p);

    System.Xml.XmlTextReader xmlReader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new StringReader(s));
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);

    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your requirements. Now please post your attempt...

Answer (score 0):

set gridview property as follows to position it in center

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" RowStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center" ...>
```

m not gettin wat you exactly need...
but place your `txtbox` and `gridview` inside the `table`

Comment: my requirement is i need my gridview to be aligned it in the generated pdf file.